# Stop cardboard from warping when impregnating with polyester resin

Tags: composite-resin

I have a guitar and also the rectangular cardboard box which it was delivered in. I want to make a more durable carry case for the guitar using the cardboard delivery box. It seems a shame to throw away a perfectly good box which is already the correct size and I don't want to buy a guitar case just yet. Dimensions of the box are 100x45x17 centimeters. The cardboard is made from two layers of corrugated material sandwiched in three layers of flat. I find from research that the cardboard needs to be sealed first with pva/wood glue after which fine woven glass cloth and then polyester resin can be applied. In previous experiments (when I didn't understand the necessity to seal it first) the cardboard warped and destroyed the shape of my project which was a tea tray. My question is how can I stop the cardboard from warping? If successful with the glassfibre I then want to apply a final color coat( I think this is called a gel coat).

Comment: Since you talk about waste of throwing it out, consider that the box will have been made unrecyclable when you inevitably get rid of it since it is only temporary, and you will have also added a bunch of resins, glues and glass to the landfill. You can get cases or bags for well under $100USD.

Comment: Thank you so much. Consider this, any replies to this question come via a complex network of electronic equipment which I will list here for your benefit. Your device, a phone or computer, the router it is connected to, the next router or mobile phone base station, the switch that comes next in the link, the central mobile network or internet provider which comes next and then more switches and routers before your comment gets to me. Thats quite a lot of equipment containing rare earths, pvc insulation, paint etc. Have you considered how your own use of resources fits into the picture?

Comment: I do. Which is why I hunted through the dumper last week for a bag full of metal chips that the cleaning staff threw out that should have gone to the metal recycler. Look, I'm not saying don't glass anything. I'm saying that if you're going to go the effort then you might as well get some foam insulation panels from the hardware store, cut out a nice shaped guitar case from that and glass that. You'll get something with better results that lasts longer for the effort you put in rather than using good glass and resin on a sub-par substrate that will only to be thrown out.

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like there is some difficulty in providing useful input here. What do you think I should do with the box? Are you suggesting that a case which I buy from a shop will last forever and will never need to be itself recycled? In your analysis of recycing and resources which you applied to my query about composite materials you did not mention the resource costs of me obtaining a case from a shop. How much of the $100 cost of the case is recyclable materials? How much is the unrecoverable cost of resources used in transport to the shop or in me travelling to buy it?

Comment: I'm not suggesting a case you get from the shop will never be thrown out. Everything ultimately gets thrown out. But if you're going to use glass and resin on something, for what you're doing it's not a big leap to use something a little better than cardboard which will altogether last longer (and be easier to glass since it doesn't needing sealing and won't warp, at least it won't warp from the resin itself) which ultimately makes less stuff thrown out. Like a bunch of disposable cups versus one good cup.

Comment: If you ever bought a $100 guitar case from a shop you would know that at this price they are all made of plastic. In 40 years of buying various musical instruments I've not yet seen a guitar case made entirely from recyclable materials. I think my post may be one where you are unable to provide sensible comments. There may be other forums where your input is more valuable but thank you for your advice. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think @DKNguyen makes good points and given the amount of experimentation you need to do to "possibly" achieve an acceptable result, then your point about his router and other equipment should be considered against the number of effective posts made by DK on a daily basis...

Comment: Thank you @Solar Mike for your comment. Please confine your comments to the subject of cardboard, warping, resins and fibreglass. I will now try to close this post in order to avoid comments like yours. DKNguyen did not answer the question but commented on other matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that the typical multi-layer corrugated cardboard material has all the flutes running parallel/in the same direction. In order to minimize the warping you are experiencing, it would be necessary to create additional layers by using adhesive to bond "cross-grain" cardboard to the existing surface. You'd have to pick an adhesive, perhaps via experimentation that would not create warping while being applied or while curing.

PVA/wood glue is water based and will indeed warp while creating the new layers. Contact cement is not water based (unless you buy that particular product!) and will provide strong bonds between layers.

Additionally, gel coat is usually applied as the first layer within a mold, excluding ambient atmosphere during the curing process. Be sure to select a gel coat product which provides for this aspect of your build. For outer skin application, the terms "[gel coat with wax](https://support.jamestowndistributors.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022132074-What-s-the-difference-between-gelcoat-with-wax-and-without-wax-)" will provide suitable results in a search. Useful information at the linked site.

Comment: Bearing in mind your comment on multi layer cardboard it seems I will have to do a lot of experimentation on similar scrap material. The uni-directional flutes may be an insurmountable problem. I think I'll just put duct tape on the edges and it will probably hold together for a couple of years.